# Data e Hora POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, delphi

Olá, bom dia! Estou criando um relatório no fastreport para conseguir consultar o ticket médio de um restaurante, uma das informações que tenho que colocar nesse relatório é quanto tempo a mesa ficou aberta. Eu tenho duas tabelas na minha database, uma de dataHora que a mesa é aberta e uma de dataHora que ela é fechada, eu precisava saber se há uma função no SQL que eu possa pegar esse tempo que elas ficaram abertas, sendo mais específico eu gostaria de calcular a diferença de tempo entre as duas datas, sabe? Assim eu teria quanto tempo a mesa ficou aberta

[Print da DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37hl7.png) Como na imagem ao lado, a primeira mesa indicada ficou aberta apenas por 11 segundos, eu gostaria de saber se há alguma função disponível para me retornar que a mesa ficou aberta apenas 11 segundos entende? Eu pesquisei sobre isso e não achei nada relacionado e também não tenho ideia de como poderia fazer.

Eu já tentei pesquisar no próprio site do PostgreSQL e também no youtube, mas não encontrei nada relacionado, acredito que eu esteja procurando errado também.

Comment: Eu faria a conta em segundos ou minutos e depois converteria para exibição , creio que se queira saber o tempo médio que um mesa fica aberta. Creio que a AGE complique o cálculo. https://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff .... https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-timestamps-in-postgresql/

Comment: Não publique links de imagens , publique como texto , use apenas a tag do SGBD em questão

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função [AGE](https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/age-function.php) passando as duas colunas como parâmetro:

```
SELECT
    AGE(pve_dt_hr_fechamento_pedido, pve_dt_hr_emissao) as duracao
FROM ...
```